# Preserve InitSelection -Select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a Select2, ajax data provided, at my page.
I need to implement a edition of previous selected options...
So now i can, through initselection, show the previous option. Unfortunately when i start writing and select the new value, the previous options are removed.

Its possible to preserve de previous data until the user remove,explicitly?

Code:

```
$("#FAMILIAS").select2({
    language: "pt",

    ajax: {
        url: "GET_JSONDATA.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',   
        delay: 600,
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            q: params.term, // search term
            page: params.page,
            _FORN:1,
          };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
          params.page = params.page || 1;
          currentRequestFamilias=null;

          return {

            results: data.items,
            pagination: {
              more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
            }
          };
        },
        cache: true,
        beforeSend : function()
        {           
            if(currentRequestFamilias != null)
            {
                currentRequestFamilias.abort();
            }
            if(!FornecedorEscolhido())
            {
                return false;
            }   

        },

    }
    ,
     initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        LoadInicialValues();
        if(FamiliasIniciais_==null)
            return;
        callback(FamiliasIniciais_);
    },
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  templateResult: formatoItemSelecionado, //id

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just find one possible way to do that.
it might be usefull for people, that need load data at start and give the user a way to add or delete the data....

So you will need this simple

```
var SELECT2=$("#SELECT2_CMB");
var newState = new Option(text, id, true, true);
SELECT2.append(newState).trigger('change');
```

Hope it helps someone

Best Regards